# A better way to find the radius of the complex roots of $(z + 1)^5 = 32z^5$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, circles, quintics

I was gnawing on this problem today:

> All the complex roots of $(z + 1)^5 = 32z^5,$ when plotted in the complex plane, lie on a circle. Find the radius of this circle.

I solved this by first dividing
$$
\left(\frac{z+1}{2z}\right)^5 = 1
$$
then using the roots of unity, and solving for complex $z$. Then, I did regression to determine the solution equation to be
$$
\left(x - \frac{1}{3}\right)^2 + y^2 = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2
$$
Thus, the radius is $2/3$.
Gross. That is (in my opinion) an absolutely awful way to solve this, and not the intended way. I know that there exists a better, *non-numerical* solution to this problem; Could you please help me find it?

Comment: Hint: $\,\left|\frac{z-(-1)}{z - 0}\right|=2\,$, and the locus of points in the plane with constant ratio between the distances to the two fixed points is a [circle of Apollonius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius#Apollonius.27_definition_of_a_circle) whose diameter is easily determined.

Answer (score 4):

Note that
$$
\frac{z+1}{z}=1+\frac1z
$$
Now solve $$\left(1+\frac1z\right)^5=32$$ with respect to $\frac1z$ and find the circle the solutions lie on. Then apply the reciprocal map to the resulting circle to find the circle where the $z$-solutions lie. In the complex plane, the reciprocal is [inversion in the unit circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry#Inversion_in_a_circle), composed with complex conjugation.

Comment: With $z = x + yi$, I got $x^2 + y^2 = x - yi$, and I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: @obr If that is true, then you must have $y = 0$, else the left side is real and the right is complex.  Thus, $y = 0$, and the only solutions are $1$ and $0$.  I think the intention is that $1 + \frac{1}{z} = 2a$, where $a$ is a 5th root of unity.

Comment: @J126 -- What do you mean by "I think the intention is that $1+1z=2a$, where $a$ is a 5th root of unity"?

Comment: @obr I know it's tempting to substitute $z=x+iy$, but in 98% of cases, that doesn't really help, and often enough it makes things more complicated. One of the beautiful things about complex numbers is how little you actually have to change from the real numbers when you work with them. Back to the problem: We have $(\frac1z -(-1))^5=2^5$. What are the solutions for $\frac1z$? Which circle do those solutions lie on?

Comment: I apologize for my thick-headedness, but I don't understand how to invert a circle. Algebraically, I can only find $z = 1$, but not the complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach.

The $5$th roots of $32$ are given by $2 \times k$, where
$k$ is one of the $5$ roots of $z^5 = 1.$

These roots are $~\displaystyle e^{i(2k\pi/5)} ~: ~k \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}.$

From the original problem, you have that

$$\left[\frac{z + 1}{z}\right]^5 = 32.$$

Therefore, $(z + 1) = z \times 2 \times e^{i(2k\pi/5)}.$

Therefore $1 = z \times \left[\left(2 \times e^{i(2k\pi/5)}\right) - 1\right].$

Therefore,

$$z = \frac{1}{\left(2 \times e^{i(2k\pi/5)}\right) - 1} = \frac{1}{\left[2\cos(2k\pi/5) - 1\right] + i \left[2\cos(2k\pi/5)\right]}. \tag1$$

Multiplying the numerator and denominator in (1) above by

$\displaystyle \left[2\cos(2k\pi/5) - 1\right] - i \left[2\sin(2k\pi/5)\right]$

gives

$$z = \frac{\left[2\cos(2k\pi/5) - 1\right] - i \left[2\sin(2k\pi/5)\right]}{5 - 4\cos(2k\pi/5)}.$$

---

**Edit**
For what it's worth, the $5$ roots of $z^5 - 1 = 0$ may be routinely converted into radical form by noting that

$$z^5 - 1 = (z - 1)(z^4 + z^3 + z^2 + z + 1).\tag2 $$

The 2nd factor in (2) above may be *conquered* by noting that $z = 0$ will not satisfy the equation.

Therefore, you have that

$$z^2 + z + 1 + \frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{z^2} = 0.$$

Then, you set $~\displaystyle w = z + \frac{1}{z}$.

Then, you note that $~\displaystyle w^2 = z^2 + \frac{1}{z^2} + 2.$

You end up with a quadratic equation in $w$ which will have $2$ roots, $w_1$ and $w_2$.

You then have $2$ separate quadratic equations :

$$z + \frac{1}{z} = w_1 ~~~\text{and}~~~ z + \frac{1}{z} = w_2.$$

You end up with the $4$ roots of the 2nd factor in (2) above.